# How to specific this context and method parameter type with typescript

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Options<T, P extends object> {
  data: T;
  methods: P & ThisType<P & { key: string }>;
}

function define<T, P extends object>(options: Options<T, P>) {
  options;
}

define({
  data: { hello: 'hello' },
  methods: {
    m1(custom, value: number) {
      return custom.hello + this.key + value;
    },
    m2(custom) {
      return this.m1(custom, 100);
    },
  },
});
```

As shown code above, Here are 3 ideas I want to implement but only 2 of them are finished.

1. ✅ Use `this.key` in method
2. ✅ Call other methods and return the result
3. ❌ First argument which named as custom need to be type `{ hello: string }` (from generic T)

Any idea how to resolve the third idea?

Notice: You may need to set `noImplicitThis: true` in tsconfig.json file to against `any`.

Answer (score 0):

At first I was overthinking this, but all you really need to do is change `P`:

```
function define<T, P extends Record<string, (custom: T, ...args: any[]) => unknown>>(options: Options<T, P>) {
  options;
}
```

Now, `P` is a record of strings to `(custom: T, ...args: any[]) => unknown`!

That means the first parameter in the methods will now always be inferred as `T`, which is what you need.

Shocked that this simple change fixes it? [Same.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=6&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8AKgDTIAKyEAHpCACZ7LYBGAVhAmAHzIDeAWABQyZPThg4ALmREA3MNEBbCGAAW2RjMoAyWWuB4iAT3QQCu-sgDWEYzLxgooAObIAvtwVD3w4TABXEC4cEDEIGFBzUgoqWggGJgAlTmwoegJHZxAXMgAKBADHbCUZGIA6SrgoFzwZOBBjAG0AXQBKZABeXiDrEGwAdxBubjzsTFC6tAncQhjybg7BEWYZ-G9fIWF6CKi85dFxSRk+ZDUIABsL7BkAcnOr7FuPEkVkFXVNKYPRd4BGApFMAlMgANzgFwCEBkIACShY0CWb1+yCgqgCUDChWKSnKD2uyAA1Mh1IZyrZjETkODIRBvCj3K8VsoAEyAnFI5m-NFgDFhUl4cpKAHY4FKMh-AAMkra9N+jLeCp8sqAA)